# LitElement - How to create dom-if restamp behavior with javascript if expression inside LitElement render method?

Tags: lit-element, dom-if

We are using "if" expression inside LitElement to selectively render content in render method and would like to re-create child DOM every time "if" expression get re-evaluated(changes). This is something similar to what dom-if element used to support with "restamp" property in polymer 3.

Really appreciate any pointers here to follow?

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: Doesn't it do that by default? I think you have to use cache (https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#cache) to get the other behavior.

Comment: Also https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#caching-template-results-the-cache-directive

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options depending on whether the condition will change several times and you want to cache the represented parts or not:

**Without cache (vanilla javascript)**

```
render() {
  return html`${
    condition ?
    () => html`Your TRUE HTML here` :
    () => html`Your FALSE HTML here`
  }`;
}
```

**With cache (using cache directive from lit-html)**

```
import { cache } from 'lit-html/directives/cache';
[…]
render() {
  return html`${cache(
    condition ?
    () => html`Your TRUE HTML here` :
    () => html`Your FALSE HTML here`
  )}`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    render() {
      return html`${
        condition ? html`<p>Hello</p>` : ''
      }`;
    }
```